# Close a cluetip when the mouse is off of the link

Tags: javascript, jquery, cluetip

Is there an option to close a `cluetip` dialog when the mouse is moved off of the link? There is the `mouseOutClose` option, but it doesn't close the `cluetip` if you don't hover over it first.

Here is an example:

http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/demo/ - the first link under the **jTip Theme**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the clueTips core file
replace the code:

```
if (opts.mouseOutClose) {....}
```

with

```
if (opts.mouseOutClose) {
var closectip;
$cluetip.hover(function() {
clearTimeout(closectip);
},
function() {
$closeLink.trigger('click');
});
$this.hover(function() {
clearTimeout(closectip);

}, function() {
closectip = setTimeout(cluetipClose, 1000);
});
}
```

I found the solution from a jquery forum here is the link

http://plugins.jquery.com/content/cluetip-doesnt-close-mouseout

Its working for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same trouble, and I got a solution.

It's working.

So, what we all want is a way to

1- showing cluetip when link is hovered, then discard it when mouse goes out

2- BUT keep cluetip opened if the mouse did go inside so that it can click on links inside the cluetip

This is how to do it.

Just add this parameter :

```
sticky:    true, 
onShow:   function(){ 
                 $('.mylink').mouseout(function() {     // if I go out of the link, then...
                    var closing = setTimeout(" $(document).trigger('hideCluetip')",400);  // close the tip after 400ms
                    $("#cluetip").mouseover(function() { clearTimeout(closing); } );    // unless I got inside the cluetip
                 });
          }
```

This is it !

Answer (score -1):

It's because the sticky option is set to true...

Comment: Yes and it should be... I have some links in cluetip so I don't want it to disappear when the mouse is over the cluetip... sticky option is the only way to do that.

Comment: I need to change the way cluetip closes... When the mouse is out of link it should close automatically but when the mouse is over the cluetip itself it shouldn't. cluetip can be closed using $(document).trigger('hideCluetip'); function so I tried adding onmouseout="$(document).trigger('hideCluetip');" but it closes cluetip even the mouse is over the cluetip itself... Any ideas?